# HTML & CSS: triggering active class for a section in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css

So normally when I visit for ex "index.html" and I give my a href link in my navbar the class "active" or whatever class and colour it so it defines which page I'm on

so

```
<a href="index.html" class="active">
```

and

```
a.active {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: white;
}
```

would just do the trick and highlights the page I'm currently on in the navbar

but I have a section in my index.html which I can go to by clicking on this in the navbar

```
<a href="index.html#about">
```

but if I trigger the class="active" for this section, then both the index and the section will be highlighted in my navbar

how do I make it so that when I'm on the section, my index.html loses its class=active and for the section to gain that class?

possibly if this could be done using only CSS!

**TL;DR**  I need a way in CSS/JS that adds/removes the class for whatever element(s) I want it to be on.

Comment: I think you'll have to show the script you're using which actually applies that `.active` class.

Comment: @xFranko will you want do a effect like this? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/scrollspy/

Comment: @Raxi I'm not using any script, it's just a simple css

a.active {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: white;
}

Comment: @Usiel yes that's exactly what I want, to highlight a tab in my navbar when i'm on a certain section in the page

Comment: I understand that `.active` is a class which has some CSS assigned to it; But elements only gain classes in 1 of 2 ways. Either the class is literally assigned (as in `<a class="active">`) in which case it would always be in effect (which clearly doesn't match your use case); or a script (be it serverside or clientside) adds/removes the class for whatever element(s) you want it to be on. *(that is unless you're confusing `:active` with `.active`, but i doubt that)*

Comment: yes it's the latter, a script to add/remove the class for whatever element is what i meant !

Comment: yea, you'll have to edit that one into your question to provide some context on whats going on; either that or go with one of those off the shelf spyscrollers, which others have already linked to.

Comment: @Raxi I edited the question and I will look into the spyscrollers stuff that others linked, thank you

Comment: quite a lot libraries have such functions, Bootstrap, fullPage.js, etc. btw, don't mix up Java with JavaScript, they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**, The function you want in your project is called scrollspy and it is achieved with javascript. You can use the bootstrap or create the function in pure javascript. But in order not to reinvent the wheel I show you an example based on a vanilla javascript script from: https://github.com/cferdinandi/gumshoe.

```js
var spy = new Gumshoe('#my-awesome-nav a');
```

```css
html {
    overflow-y: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*  Sets body width */
.container {
    max-width: 90em;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/**
 * Grid
 */
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2em;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

#my-awesome-nav {
    position: fixed;
}

#my-awesome-nav li.active {
    background-color: black;
}

#my-awesome-nav li.active a {
    color: white;
}

/**
 * Sections
 */
.section {
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 95vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
}

#eenie {
    background-color: #0088cc;
}

#meenie {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

#miney {
    background-color: #272727;
}

#mo {
    background-color: #f42b37;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/gumshoe/dist/gumshoe.polyfills.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <nav>
            <ul id="my-awesome-nav">
                <li><a href="#eenie">Eenie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#meenie">Meenie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#miney">Miney</a></li>
                <li><a href="#mo">Mo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
      <div class="section" id="eenie">
                Eenie...
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="meenie">
                Meenie...
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="miney">
                Miney...
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="mo">
                Mo...
            </div>
      
            <p><a data-scroll href="#top">Back to the top</a></p>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```